# ClearCase won't allow Check-In

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm rather new to ClearCase but have searched through a lot of solutions to the following problem without success.  When I try to do a check-in I get the following error.

> Error checking in 'MY FILE'
>       No premission to perform operation "checkin"
>       Must be one of: object creator, element owner, VOB owner, member of ClearCase grop
>       Unable to checking "MY FILE"

I've verified that I am in fact in the ClearCase group and have checked the registry entries that are required for it to work correctly.  If I wasn't able to check-out then I would suspect my groups were messed up, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three criteria to check when confronted with a ClearCase permission issue are:

1/ the "`credmap`" (credential mapping)

type "`credmap VOB_Server_Hostname`" and check what is currently your primary group (see also the value of `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable)

2/ the view protection rights

type "`cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`" anywhere within your view, and see if the primary group is correct

3/ the primary and secondary groups of the vob

type "`cleartool descr -l vob:\yourVob`", with "`yourVob`" the Vob (Version Object Database or "repository") supposed to contain "yourFile".

The last point is important because if your primary group is not one of the groups associated with "`yourVob`", then you won't have the right to make a checkin.

Check also the protection rights of the parent directory (see in particular if the execution bit is set).

Comment: I figured it out.  It was because there was another person with the same exact account name.  Quite the permissions issue indeed.

Comment: @GrandPrix: good catch. I rarely see that issue in my LDAP Active Directory environment ;)